# passing cmd line arguments to powershell script - how to exit if no arguements

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, cmd, powershell-2.0

So far I have my .ps1 file with this

```powershell
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelin=$true)][string[]] $appPoolArray)
$zero = 0
if ($appPoolArray.length -eq $zero){
Write-Output "no app pools where selected"
exit
}
else {
foreach ($elem in $appPoolArray)
$appPool = Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsApplicationPool" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$elem"}
$appPool.Recycle()
Write-Output "Recycled."
Start-Sleep -Second 60
}
Write-Output "Done."
}
```

I would like to make it so if there is no arguments in the cmd line then it exits right away, instead it just asks me to keep adding elements into the array if I did not include arguements in the command (The command I am running in cmd line is powershell -noexit path\script.ps1) I'm not very good with Powershell or scripts in general but I know the error is with the if statement. Help would be appreciated

Edit: I tried taking out the Write-Mandatory=$True but it now gives me an error when I dont pass any arguements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out `Mandatory=$True` and add a missing brace at the end of `foreach..` line. In the future use indents and format your code as you will find it easier to spot these errors(or use a tool like PowerGUI(http://www.quest.com/powergui-freeware))

```powershell
Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]] $appPoolArray)
    if ($appPoolArray -eq $null){
        Write-Output "no app pools where selected"           
    }
    else {
        foreach ($elem in $appPoolArray){
            $appPool = Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsApplicationPool" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/APPPOOLS/$elem"}
            $appPool.Recycle()
            Write-Output "Recycled."
            Start-Sleep -Second 60
        }
    Write-Output "Done."
    }
```

I changed 2nd line to `if ($appPoolArray -eq $null){` as it shows your intentions more clearly but your original statement will work too.

Comment: Thanks! I tried taking out the Mandatory=$True and it still didn't work, I didn't even realize I was missing the opening bracket. I appreciate the help.